# What's another way of saying "supposed to graduate in 2013"?

Tags: american-english, dictionaries

I am filling out a job application and I know there's an official word for it, but I just can't think of it. It can normally be found on transcripts.

Comment: If they can be normally be found on transcripts, have you tried checking one? You can usually get unofficial ones for free.

Comment: Maybe you could provide more context from the application so we may better answer your question. It's too open-ended at this point.

Answer (score 2):

I've always thought "expected" was appropriate for this.Maybe "anticipated"?

Answer (score 1):

*Class of 2013* means just that — you are expected to graduate in 2013 based on your current status.

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives I've seen:

- *class of 2013*
- *class of '13*
- *Projected graduation date: 2013*
- *Projected graduation date: May, 2013*
- *Projected graduation date: May 10, 2013*
- *Expected graduation date: 2013*
- *Expected graduation date: May, 2013*
- *Expected graduation date: May 10, 2013*

Answer (score -3):

> - I am a candidate for graduation this year.
> - In God's grace, I am about to fulfill my bachelor degree and will graduate on the 16th of April this year.
> - I will graduate on...
> - I am about to graduate on...